# "Ui" file not updating when a QAction widget is removed in the GUI

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have deleted an action in the Qt Creator GUI, but it still appears in the "ui" file:

```
<action name="actionFoo">
 <property name="text">
  <string>Foo</string>
 </property>
</action>
```

Do I have to remove it from the file too? Or is there a way to rebuild the file?

Comment: try clean and execute qmake

Comment: @vcloarec: That won't do anything. `clean` and `qmake` don't change source files, and the '.ui' file is a source file like any .py, .h, .cpp, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing an action from a menu doesn't delete that action. You need to delete it yourself.

In `Qt Designer` there is an `Action Editor` (in menu `View`) where you can delete any action from the context menu.

In `Qt Creator` it can be found in `Window -> Views -> Action Editor` (that's a guess! I'm using the german version.)

At last, you can always edit your .ui file manually (sometimes neccessary if Qt Creator isn't flexible enough). You can't do that from Qt Creator, but with any external text editor. Just make sure to delete the complete XML node and don't create invalid XML...